# Display Image after listitemclicked

Tags: java, android, imageview, listactivity

So i've searched and searched and I've found nothing like I'm looking. I have several ListActivities and I can click one and go to the next list and next list etc... What I want is when i click on the appropriate list item i want it to display an image from the res folder. I have been stuck on this all afternoon and nothing is working that i can find. Any help would be great. Example When CoverSheet is selected it retrieves cover_sheet.png.
Thanks James

The entry point of the application: `Menu.java`

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity 
{ 
    public static final String EXTRA_PICTURE = "extra.picture.toshow"; 

    String classes[] = { "CoverSheet",// "TreatmentProtocols", "EMSProcedures",
           // "DrugList", "EMSPolicies", "EMSTriageAndDestinationPlan",  
           // "Appendices"
            }; 
    //in this array you store the drawable resource ids to show.  
    //you can change it to hold urls or other identifiers. 
    int images[] = { R.drawable.cover_sheet, }; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes)); 
    } 

    protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview); 
        final int imgResource = getIntent().getIntExtra(Menu.EXTRA_PICTURE, 0);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img); 
        img.setImageResource(imgResource); }

    @Override 
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    { 
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 
        String Menu = classes[position]; 
        try 
        { 
            Class firstClass = Class.forName("protocols.NashCounty." + Menu); 
            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, firstClass); 
            firstIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE, images[position]); 
            startActivity(firstIntent); 
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        { 
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "ClassNotFoundException ", e); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "Exception ", e); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This is my Class i've created

```
public class CoverSheet extends ListActivity
{
    public static final String EXTRA_PICTURE = "extra.picture.toshow";
    String classes[] = { "CoverSheet", };
    // in this array you store the drawable resource ids to show.
    // you can change it to hold urls or other identifiers.
    int images[] = { R.drawable.cover_sheet };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
        final int imgResource = getIntent().getIntExtra(
                CoverSheet.EXTRA_PICTURE, 0);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageResource(imgResource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String coversheet = classes[position];
        try
        {
            Class firstClass = Class.forName("protocols.NashCounty."+classes);
            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(CoverSheet.this, firstClass);
            firstIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE, images[position]);
            startActivity(firstIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "ClassNotFoundException ", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "Exception ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my xml layout l named imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cover_sheet" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and below is my minifest

```
<activity android:name=".activity.CoverSheet"  
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" /> 
</application>
</manifest>
```

i was misunderstanding what you were saying earlier and i apologize for that i think im starting to undestand it...i think.

below is my logcat error when trying to run the code:

05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=3
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at protocols.NashCounty.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:40)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-18 17:15:26.221: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I don't see any code regarding displaying an image here...

Comment: Can you explain where you want to display image.

Comment: I want the picture to pull up full screen after you click a parameter in the list array..ex when I click on coversheet it pulls up the picture cover sheet in full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are showing images in the activities whose names are listed inside the `classes` variable.

Make sure all the classes listed there are also included in the `androidManifest.xml` with a proper `<activity />`tag and with the correct package declaration!

Your use of casing the variables and package names is misleading, but I think your application package is `protocols.NashCountry`, so inside the manifest there should be a line similar to this:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.CoverSheet" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

for each activity class you want to call.

You should also try to change the

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

into

```
Log.e("SAMPLE", "ClassNotFoundException ", e);
```

**Edit**: To make your subsequent activities to be displayed in full screen, you need to set `android:theme` attribute in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.CoverSheet" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
<activity android:name=".activity.TreatmentProtocols" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

the code below shows how to deal with `Intent` extras:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity
{
    public static final String EXTRA_PICTURE = "extra.picture.toshow";
    String classes[] = { "CoverSheet", "TreatmentProtocols", "EMSProcedures", 
            "DrugList", "EMSPolicies", "EMSTriageAndDestinationPlan", 
            "Appendices" };
    //in this array you store the drawable resource ids to show. 
    //you can change it to hold urls or other identifiers.
    int images[] = { R.drawable.coversheet, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, 
        R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String Menu = classes[position];
        try
        {
            Class firstClass = Class.forName("protocols.NashCounty." + Menu);
            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, firstClass);
            firstIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE, images[position]);
            startActivity(firstIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "ClassNotFoundException ", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("SAMPLE", "Exception ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the `onCreate` methods in your classes should display the proper image based on the `extra` provided to them:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_img);
    final int imgResource = getIntent().getIntExtra(Menu.EXTRA_PICTURE, 0);
    final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageResource(imgResource);
}
```

Please note, that if you just need to display different images based on list item clicks, you don't need separate activities, and you don't have to access them by name: you should use a single activity, and pass the id of the image to it as an extra parameter when starting the intent.

**Edit:** Your `CoverSheet` activity class should look like this:

```
public class CoverSheet extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
        final int imgResource = getIntent().getIntExtra(Menu.EXTRA_PICTURE, 0);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageResource(imgResource);
    }
}
```

It is very simple, no need to extend `ListActivity`, since you don't want to deal with any list there, you just want to display a picture.

Other variables are also useless for this scenario!

**Edit 2**: Your `onListItemClick` method should get simpler too! There is no need for dynamically retrieve classes, so you can completely remove the `classes` array variable from your `Menu` activity as well.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try
    {
        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CoverSheet.class);
        firstIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE, images[position]);
        startActivity(firstIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("SAMPLE", "Exception ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an activity for each class I've created. Do I need one for each parameter within the array as well?  I'll change the other asap. See my above comment to see if it clarifies what I'm looking for better. Thanks again for your help

Comment: the `startActivity(firstIntent);` call suggests, that you are trying start a new `Activity` extension of a class by the name of `Class.forName("protocols.NashCounty."+ Menu)`. Here `Menu` is a local variable that holds a values from your `classes[]` array, so YES, you should have those classes defined too: `protocols.NashCountry.CoverSheet`, `protocols.NashCountry.TreatmentProtocols`, ...

Comment: Thanks I think I have that. But how do I get it to pull up the picture associated when the value within the array is selected? Sorry for not understanding completely.

Comment: you can pass `extras` to your `Intent`: `firstIntent.putExtra("my.image.location", "the location of the image you want to show");` Then in the activity you've just started you extract that `extra` by `final String imageLocation = getIntent().getStringExtra("my.image.location");`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll let you know how it goes. And thanks for your fast response as well!!

Comment: I've tried several variations and I cannot get the above to work without errors...sorry for my redundancy I'm a fairly new programmer(<1 yr) and still learning. i'm not understanding this extras.. is that a variable i need to create?

Comment: Maybe I've made progress not sure though...Do i need to make another class for where I want to display the image..or will something like image view work? still not sure how to display it full screen?

Comment: // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  String Menu = classes[position];
  try{
   Class firstClass = Class.forName("protocols.NashCounty."+ Menu);
   Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, firstClass);
   firstIntent.putExtra("/Protocols/res/drawable-hdpi/cover_sheet.png", "protocols.NashCounty.cover_sheet");
   startActivity(firstIntent);
   final String imageLocation = getIntent().getStringExtra("/Protocols/res/drawable-hdpi/cover_sheet.png");
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    Log.e("Menu", "ClassNotFoundException ", e);

Comment: i can't get it to read this line. I've tried several things even putting the drawable in  but it won't run after the splash screen. final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img)

Comment: you should of course change the `splash.xml` to point to your desired layout. And inside that layout you should have an `ImageView` declared, with the @id attribute set to `img`. Inside that image view will the desired picture be laid. You probably have that `ImageView` with a different @id, so please change it to fit your needs: `final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageview_id)`.

Comment: ok thanks I know you've got me on right track. Still can't get it to work but Ill play with it some more and see what i can do i've got a headache from it now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: If the difference between all the activities listed in your `classes[]` array is the displayed images and texts, but they have common layout and behavior, then your should go for a single activity there (no need of `Class.forName` calls) say `ImageActivity`, and pass to it all the `extra` parameters you need (image locations, texts...). Then in the `ImageActivity`'s `onCreate` method you simply retrieve the `extras` as shown above, and fill the layout based on their values.

Comment: ive edited above code and I have it where there are no errors but still no picture dispayed. i have the activity for coversheet int he manifest and ive created a xml file with it the cover_sheet image placed with imageview. So i feel im close but something minor is off. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: The `onCreate1` method should be placed inside the `CoverSheet` activity, the code of it must be part of the `CoverSheet`'s `onCreate` method. That's the point where you have to retrieve the passed image's `@id`, and display it in your `ImageView`. If still having problems, please share the code and the xml layout of the `CoverSheet` activity.

Comment: thank you, I've re-added your `Menu` class too, because it is relevant! Please see my update, and remove all the useless variables / methods from your `CoverSheet` class: it has to be a very simple class. Your layout is ok, but maybe `fill_parent` for both the `layout_width` and `layout_height` would be better :)

Comment: ive changed the code and now when i click on a menu item instead of taking me to the next list or showing the cover sheet i get an logcat error and it shuts doen the app. I've added the logcat.

Comment: what do you mean by 'next list'??? your initial request was to show up an image when a list item is clicked. for that you don't need two lists. please see my update.

Comment: it is and was my question and never intended to mislead you, but some of the items menu class have other matching classes that take you to another class that has a array that will take you to the picture needed. I planned on getting the coversheet to work and i would then do the hard work of writing the code for the other 170 items between all the classes.

Comment: Then you should create a new activity: `PictureActivity` that looks exactly like the `CoverSheet` class I've posted, and start it with the necessary `extra` whenever you want to show a picture. And roll back the `CoverSheet` activity as you wrote it to be a `ListView`. But I'm sure if you'd experience a bit more in activities you'd find out that you don't need separate classes for all the items, just need to decide upon which extra what to show up next :)

Comment: thanks again for all your help. I'll work on it some more and see if i can at least get the coversheet to display the image and then ill go back and work on the other again.